# Ionic Google Maps Marker Disappear on iOS and Safari

Tags: ios, cordova, google-maps, ionic-framework

I'm running into a problem where Google Maps Marker will disappear after a user goes back into the map for the second time. It works perfectly on Android, but iOS not so great. Has anyone encounter this problem?

I've also noticed this problem occurs in Safari too when I run it in the Safari Browser. Instead of the markers not appearing the second time visit, the map doesn't appear to show.

---Update---

Well, I figure out the problem. On the phone, you will have to rotate the device back n forth for the markers to appear again and on Safari, you will have to resize the browser for the markers to appear again.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Google Maps plugin for cordova:

https://github.com/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps

There you have several options to set the behavior of the markers.

An important reason for using the plugin is, that the traffic caused by the map is very small comparing to the javascript solution. The plugin uses vectors like the map.app.